# error: The setter 'observer' isn't defined for the type 'Bloc<Event, State>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm using flutter_bloc and according to [this example](https://%20https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc/example) I want to observe the bloc.
but I get this error:

```
error: The setter 'observer' isn't defined for the type 'Bloc<Event, State>'. (undefined_setter at [login_bloc_project] lib\main.dart:12)
```

when calling this method:

```
void main() {
  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () => runApp(const MyApp()),
    blocObserver: MyBlocObserver(),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your package version might be lower than v8.1.0. **BlocObserver is updated** with that version. You can upgrade your dependency to solve this.

For more info:
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=v810